# 20 Hz subsonic 350 W RC low pass filter

Tags: circuit-design, low-pass, passive-filter, cutoff-frequency

I build [rotary subwoofers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_woofer) that produce ULF (subsonic) sound levels ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe57fIgJgNI)) .
The amplifier that I use is 12V 350W and supplies up to 25 amps.

I would like to create a reasonably high quality, strong passive filter that has a cut off frequency of 22 Hz.

I would also like to use nth order because it must have a very steep roll-off, e.g. nothing over 30 Hz max. My only concern is that the roll off will affect frequencies below 20 Hz. Is this possible without having to use digital controllers?

Comment: yes  active filter design tool at Ti.com easy peasy

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 true, but he's explicitly asking for a passive filter

Comment: For passive filters it is not easy to have high order LPF with good dampening with just air, better to make it flat response with servo control using reflector on cone and active filters.

Comment: Chris, it's much easier to read if you pay more attention to the capitalization of words (especially at the beginning of sentences). Since good readability increases the likelihood of people reading your question, I took the freedom of improving your question with respect to that slightly :)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 that was a bit hard to understand. But yeah, of course you get steeper responses / shorter roll-off with active filters, but the point is that passive filters between amplifiers and speakers are usually used because you can then use a single amplifier to drive all your speaker elements. Your proposed active filter would effectively be a second amplifier, wouldn't it?

Comment: Of course, subs normally are self powered  http://www.rythmikaudio.com/DirectServo.html

Comment: Using two amplifiers might be cheaper since the majority of the power goes to the low frequency side which has a relatively narrow bandwidth.

Comment: @user3528438 thanks fo the suggestion but that isnt an option

Comment: it would probably still be the better, and maybe even cheaper, option in total: if you need total output power of maybe 300 W, then you can use your current amp only for the subwoofer, and use a less powerful amp for the upper frequencies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, true, but the unit cannot go over 30hz as a maximum, plus, using a second amp would mean i would need second PSU to run them which would defeat the object of how efficient the unit is

Comment: "cannot go over 30 Hz" is *easy* with a low-power active or digital filter *feeding* an amplifier, but very hard with a high-power passive filter. And no, you're totally wrong about efficiency. The *passive* filter is inefficient. Only amplifying the signal that you sub needs is power-efficient.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so if i was to use a low power active filter for this, what do i need? i would like to keep it as "analogue" as possible

Comment: This whole thing doesn't make much sense. The mechanical construction is already a strong low-pass filter, it just can't output anything above 25 Hz, likely. And I am wondering, how this modulated fan deals with turbulent noise from rotating blades?

Comment: It is senseless old school thinking to use one  Amplifer and passively share 90% of the power to a subwoofer at the expense of crossovers and loss of efficiency. It has zero benefit!!

Comment: Examine commercial solutions this design has been done many times by many ... even Logitech

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 i cant use 2 amps. simple as that. thee is only one amp and it runs the unit. there is nothing else to be run. like i said, im going to look into active filtering

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing together some numbers:

Per passive RC filter stage, you get 6 dB roll-off per octave.

You need your transition to happen between 22 Hz and 30 Hz, that means you want some let's say 40 dB attenuation in ca half a decade. That demands, very roughly, a steepness of 80 dB per decade. So, a 13-stage passive filter.

So, we can simply rule that out practically.

Comment: thanks, even 13 stages would be fine. this is a specialist unit and would like customers who want these units to be satisfied :)

Comment: no. 13 stages is just *necessary*. It's not a good filter. The losses would be humongous, the device would be huge, the accuracy would be bad, the phase linearity would be terrible, the price would be high, the thing might be about as heavy as the subwoofer. If you got customers with any idea of what a good device is, then they won't accept this.

Comment: so what would you propose to keep the output clean and have a steep roll-off but also power efficient?

Comment: Tony and I have been repeatedly telling you. I really don't think I need to repeat this,but: Have two separate amplifiers, one for the sub, one for the rest. These amplifiers have *active* or (probably better, even) *digital* input filters (or they are actually DACs and get digital signals instead of analog ones, and then only get the right frequency ranges to begin with).That's cheap,it only requires each of the amplifiers to produce power in the bands that their speakers are working in,and you don't burn lots and lots of watts in the passive output filters.You get adjustable phase delay,too.

Comment: there isnt anything else to be run from this amplifier. if you watch the video in the link in my OP youll see that the unit is a single entity. nothing else is run from it so i dont understand why you think that i need a second amp to run everything else, there is nothing else to run.

Comment: Then why on earth do you want a filter on the amplifier *output*? A halfway OK amplifier will only give you the frequencies on the output that you feed into the amplifier. So simply don't feed in any frequency higher than 30 Hz, problem solved. Follow Tony's advice from an hour ago and just go to Ti.com and design yourself an active filter to put *before* the amp, not *after*. What!?

Comment: because that was what i thought i needed. im happy to do whatever, but the way your going on about it is though you think i know what im doing. im asking a question because i dont know the answer. i need guidance, not criticism

Comment: An active lowpass filter built around some opamps (Or a DSP) placed in the signal line BEFORE the amplifier is what you want. I would be careful about very high order filters, they usually sound dreadful, but your choice. Personally I would be very tempted to get a cheap loudspeaker management system and have a play with it, there are not expensive boxes these days and will let you fiddle with filter order, phase and delay settings easily.

Comment: @DanMills thank you, a reasonable and helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this filter @Marcus?  One Quad Op Amp with same specs.  ( but terrible Group delay during cutoff.)

Ultimately the design specs are wrong and the OP needs to become familiar with how to write specs by learning how these designs work well rather than arbitrary numbers...

Amplitude, distortion , Group Delay error, passband ripple, band-reject f, and attenuation all affect sound and need to be specified.
[image]
But for giggles here's another result of an active filter

[image]

Comment: I see now this is not an ordinary sub-woofer design